# Pivoting wider is generating rows for every new column

Tags: r, pivot

I have this data set with the following columns: variable, country, year, value. Each variable row is related to a particular variable (for example: GDP, inflation etc). And value is, obviously, the value each variable assumes at country C and year Y. So what I'm trying to do is turning these variable rows into columns, so I would have something like this: country, year, GDP, inflation.

I'm using pivot wider , but there is a problem. Suppose I have the country A with time span from 2000 to 2010. I should have only 11 rows for this country, right? So, after pivoting, it should be something like this:

```
country / year / GDP / inflation
A       / 2000 / 13  / 1
A       / 2001 / 11  / 5
...     / ...  / ... / ...
```

But, after pivoting, I have 22 rows. In 11 rows, it will have NAs for GDP and data for inflation. In the other 11 rows, I will have data for GDP and NAs for inflation. So I get this instead:

```
country / year / GDP / inflation
A       / 2000 / 13  / NA
A       / 2001 / 11  / NA
A       / 2000 / NA  / 1
A       / 2001 / NA  / 5
...     / ...  / ... / ...
```

I tried to make a hypothetical dataset and post here, but it's no use. When I use pivot wider in my hypothetical dataset, it works properly, but when I use in my dataset, which has the same structure, things go wrong.

I noticed that, if I filter my dataset with only one selected variable, the problem does not occur. So I could just make several objects in the environment for each variable and left_join them together, but it would not be very efficient...

What could I do?

Comment: Difficult to help without 1. (a sample of) your data, and 2. your R code (that works for the toy data but not your real data).

Comment: So `pivot_wider(dat, id_cols=c("country","year"), names_from="variable", values_from="value")` doesn't work?

Comment: Are variable, country, year, and value the _only_ columns in your starting dataset? Your problem can arise if there are additional columns with values that differ within the same country and year. In which case, specifying `id_cols` as in @thelatemail’s code would solve it.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Specifying the id_cols worked!